# Add ascx.cs file to production web application

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls

One of our clients has installed our web application into production.

We need to do a very quick patch to one of the aspx controls. I tried dropping the ascx and ascx.cs source files into the dir and unsurprisingly I got this error:

Exception type - HttpParseException - The base class includes the field 'foobar', but its type (UserControls_Controls_FOO) is not compatible with the type of control (ASP.usercontrols_controls_foo_ascx).

Yes, this approach is never a good idea, but is there anything I can do to the control to get it to run in the site instead of the version compiled into the DLL?

Doing a fresh install is not an option at this point.

Answer (score 0):

no , you need to get it into compiled DLL and fresh deploy only then you can see the patch working

Answer (score 0):

If you changed only ascx file you must update only it.
But if you updated ascx.cs you must Publish project and replace old bin directory with new one.

Also you can transform site to set of dynamically compiled pages, but it is hardcore old way and bad idea nowadays.